# Merging data from a separate .csv file using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I want to create two new columns in job_transitions_sample.csv and add the wage data from wage_data_sample.csv for both Title 1 and Title 2:

job_transitions_sample.csv:

```
                     Title 1                    Title 2  Count
0   administrative assistant             office manager     20
1                 accountant                    cashier      1
2                 accountant          financial analyst     22
4                 accountant          senior accountant     23
6           accounting clerk                 bookkeeper     11
7     accounts payable clerk  accounts receivable clerk      8
8   administrative assistant           accounting clerk      8
9   administrative assistant       administrative clerk     12
...
```

wage_data_sample.csv

```
                      title   wage
0                   cashier  17.00
1           sandwich artist  18.50
2                dishwasher  20.00
3                babysitter  20.00
4                   barista  21.50
5               housekeeper  21.50
6    retail sales associate  23.00
7                 bartender  23.50
8                   cleaner  23.50
9                 line cook  23.50
10               pizza cook  23.50
...
```

I want the end result to look like this:

```
                      Title 1             Title 2  Count  Wage of Title 1  Wage of Title 2
0    administrative assistant      office manager     20              NaN              NaN
1                  accountant             cashier      1              NaN              NaN
2                  accountant   financial analyst     22              NaN              NaN
...
```

I'm thinking of using dictionaries then try to iterate every column but is there a more elegant built in solution? This is my code so far:

```
wage_data = pd.read_csv('wage_data_sample.csv')
dict = dict(zip(wage_data.title, wage_data.wage))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary `d` - cannot use `dict` for varialbe name, because python code name:

```
df = pd.read_csv('job_transitions_sample.csv')
wage_data = pd.read_csv('wage_data_sample.csv')

d = dict(zip(wage_data.title, wage_data.wage))
df['Wage of Title 1'] = df['Title 1'].map(d)
df['Wage of Title 2'] = df['Title 2'].map(d)
```

Comment: why are there warnings? `df['Wage of Title 1'] = df['Title 1'].map(d)
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy`

Comment: @pellypen - is some code between `df = pd.read_csv('job_transitions_sample.csv')
wage_data = pd.read_csv('wage_data_sample.csv')` and `d = dict(zip(wage_data.title, wage_data.wage))
df['Wage of Title 1'] = df['Title 1'].map(d)
df['Wage of Title 2'] = df['Title 2'].map(d)`  ?

Comment: yes a lot of data cleaning code for job_transitions_sample.csv

Comment: @pellypen - there is some filtration? If yes, add `.copy()` like `df = df[df['col'] > 10].copy()`

Comment: a bit unrelated but any idea how this dataset can be used to provide job transition suggestions? I want to perform quantitative and qualitative analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with 2 `merge` con the 2 different Titles subsequentely.

For example, let be

- df1 : *job_transitions_sample.csv*
- df2 : *wage_data_sample.csv*

  df1.merge(df2, left_on='Title 1', right_on='title',suffixes=('', 'Wage of')).merge(df2, left_on='Title 2', right_on='title',suffixes=('', 'Wage of'))